# Remove old portlets from portal server

Tags: websphere-portal

From my RAD, I start up the websphere portal and remove a portlet ear(the portlet ear has several portlets) that was previously deployed on server. I restart the server.
But when I go on the portal home page and go Administration -->Portlet Management --> Portlets, I still see the old portlets.

How do I remove the old portlets from the portal server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Go the the Administration --> Portlet Management --> Web Modules.

Check if the application that contains the portlet is still registered. Delete the application the is containing the portlets.

If you don't want to delete the whole application you can click the trash bin in the view you mentioned behind the portlet. I'd however suggest to delete the application.